# Python regex match on length A or B?

Tags: python, regex

Normally when doing a regex you can do [regex]{n} to indicate that you want the regex to apply to n characters. Or you can do {n,m} to mean n through m characters.

What about individually? For example if I wanted to do {4 or 8 or 12}?

Comment: The 4,8,12 thing was an example, It could be any number of potential matches that doesn't necessarily fall into a nice multiplicative pattern

Comment: OK, then use `(A{4}|A{8}|A{12})`.  That gets nasty if A is big, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alternation will do the job

```
A{4}|A{8}|A{12}
```

But if A is a big regex you will be duplicating a lot which is not good. Don't some regex engines allow to define a sub regex and later reuse it. I'm interested if this exists, but I use .NET which does not support it inside the regex.

Of course nothing stands in the way by embedding a string variable a few times from the host languages in the regex.

**Update 1**

```
A{12}|A{8}|A{4}
```

can match something different than

```
A{4}|A{8}|A{12}
```

The former one can be labeled as greedy, while the latter lazy.

The latter will match the first 4 A's in AAAAAAAA while the former will match 8 A's.

The default behavior of a quantifier is greedy but since you can't make this hand made construct lazy with a ? it just depends on what you need when choosing between the 2. If you embed it in a regex you sometimes want lazy behavior.
Not embedded the former is more than likely what you intended.

Comment: No, `A{12}|A{8}|A{4}`. And please explain why.

Comment: Good note but it depends. See Update 1.

Comment: Unless you are considering the contents of a capture group, the order of the alternates makes no difference.

Comment: @chepner When the engine backtracks in the alternation if it can't find an overall match the order will influence that overall match and thus other capturing groups.

Answer (score 0):

`{m, n}` is just shorthand for repeated alternation. That is, `A{4,5}` is just short for `AAAA|AAAAA`. As Kevin points out in a comment, you may be able to represent an arbitrary set of lengths as a continues range of concatenations, but in general that's not possible. For example, any finite set of prime numbers (in unary notation) could be matched by a regular expression:

```
11|111|11111|1111111|11111111111   # Your hypothetical 1{2 or 3 or 5 or 7 or 11}
```